# Prevent logout of the application on backpressed

Tags: android, logout

I got some problem regarding my application,after login it leads to home page.In homepage on backpressed the application gets logout.Next time when i am going to open the app it starts again from login page.

I have passed the value and set the notification also,i don't know how to prevent it could anybody help me @Thanks

Comment: Are your login page and homepage two different activities ?

Comment: @user1721904 yes..two different i want to prevent the logout of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Save the login details in `SharedPreferences`.

To save login Details to SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("loginSaved", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("username", "some user value");
editor.putString("password", "some password value");
editor.commit();
```

- Check if there is value in `SharedPreference` on opening Login Page.
- If login details are saved in  SharedPreference go to home page.Else
  show the login page.

To check Logged In or not

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("loginSaved", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = sp.getString("username", null);
String password = sp.getString("password", null);
if(username != null && password != null){
    // login automatically with username and password    
}
else{
    // show login page
}
```

- Clear the loginDetails from `SharedPreference` when the user
  correctly logout.

Comment: thanks RKN but i need to prevent the logout of the application on minimize the app it is getting logout

Comment: what do you mean by preventing logout?? Restrict user to go out of the app on BackPressed??

Comment: once user login in side the app it should stay in home page only , until user pressed logout,it should not logout.

Comment: Ya, that means user didn't pressed logout and gone out of app. Then when app is relaunched he should be automatically logged in.. right??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29477/discussion-between-rkn-and-priya2134412)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your activity flow is as follows: Login -> Main. You could reverse the activities so that the main activity launches login activity as needed.

- Make your main activity also the `MAIN` activity in manifest so it is the default.
- In each activity requiring logged-in state, check for valid session or credentials in `onResume()` and launch the login activity if needed. To prevent a loop in login activity back press -> main activity resumed -> login activity launched, you can for example override login activity's `onBackPressed()` to call `moveTaskToBack(true)` to move your app to background.
- When login is successful, just `finish()` the login activity so that the previous activity such as your main activity is resumed.
- Explicit logout should clear the session/credentials data and probably launch the login activity.

This will maintain your application's back stack in a consistent state and also easily extends to multiple session-requiring activities the app can be resumed to.

To store credential/session data locally, use e.g. `SharedPreferences`.